# Unknown error while running node_mdns on node.js on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, mdns

I've been trying to create a node.js application with express that does some ZeroConf discovery on the network and runs on a Raspberry Pi. While the app is working fine on my development machine, I get an error when running it on a Raspberry Pi.

The raspberry pi is running node 0.10.5, and node_mdns as the package to do the zeroconf discovery. Al required libraries that are mentioned on the node_mdns install page are installed and up to date.

The app launches correctly, but when a device is discovered I get the following error.

```
{ [Error: dns service error: unknown] errorCode: -65537 }

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: dns service error: unknown
    at MDNSService.on_resolver_done (/home/pi/projects/test/node_modules/mdns/lib/resolver_sequence_tasks.js:19:30)
    at SocketWatcher.MDNSService.self.watcher.callback (/home/pi/projects/test/node_modules/mdns/lib/mdns_service.js:17:38)
```

It doens't seem to be a network issue, because it only happens on the raspberry pi, not on other devices in the network.

If anybody has had the same problem and managed to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This issue is now fixed, https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns/issues/70.

I'm also getting an error with Node.js, ZeroConf and the Pi. Again, it also works on my development machine, but not on the Pi. Which sort of rules out a network or code problems on my end of things,

```
node_modules/mdns/lib/advertisement.js:56
  dns_sd.DNSServiceRegister(self.serviceRef, flags, ifaceIdx, name,
         ^
Error: dns service error: unknown
    at new Advertisement (node_modules/mdns/lib/advertisement.js:56:10)
    at Object.create [as createAdvertisement] (node_modules/mdns/lib/advertisement.js:64:10)
    at /home/pi/steward/steward/core/server.js:105:10
    at Server.onListen (node_modules/portfinder/lib/portfinder.js:48:5)
    at Server.g (events.js:175:14)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at net.js:1035:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Suggestions welcome...

Comment: It looks like the linked commit/fix is not part of 0.10.x node series. Are you using 0.11?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the pi ? Cause I have same problem. Ok on mac but not on pi...